# launch several "while read" commands with xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a file that contains a list of commands like this

`while read line;do tabix ftp://.../myfile.gz. >> output.vcf; done < input.txt`

and I would like to pass this list of 45 commands to xargs.

I'm trying to call:

`cat mycommands.txt | xargs -P45 -n10 bash`
 but I'm not sure whether bash understands `>` or `>>` as an argument and it is not working.
Does anyone see something I'm not seeing? A mistake...
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the `-I` flag?

Like this

`cat mycommands.txt | xargs -P45 -n10 -I {} bash -c {}`

As it appears in the xargs man page:

> Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names
>   read  from  standard  input.

kind regards

Comment: It has been a pleasure :D